# How to construct 3D image from 2D image using Markov Random Field?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, 3d, computer-vision, 2d

I have one 2D CT image and I want to convert it to 3D image using Markov Random Field. There are several papers in the literature in which this technique was used based on 3 2D orthogonal images. However, I can't find a simple and clear resource that explains the conversion process using MRF in clear steps. Here are some papers I found,

http://www.immijournal.com/content/pdf/s40192-014-0019-3.pdf

http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1971113/

https://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/Research/Projects/CS/vision/papers/efros-iccv99.pdf

What I have understood is that the image is converted into a graph of connected pixels, and the properties of a pixel depend on the properties of its adjacent ones. Put it was not really clear how the process takes place. Also, the cost minimization process was confusing to me what parameters are we trying to minimize? And how this will lead to constructing a 3D image from the 3 2D orthogonal ones?

Can anyone please explain to me how the conversion algorithm works using MRF in steps?

Thank You

Comment: you can choose an MCMC method to sampling from the Gibbs distribution corresponding to your MRF.

Comment: Thanks, can you please elaborate more? What are the steps that I should follow, I mean how the algorithm will wok in this case?

Comment: it's hard to explain this clearly in a few lines, so i recommend you to read some books concerning this topic, such as `Markov Random Field Modeling in Image Analysis/Computer Vision`.

Comment: i find the steps are clearly described in the 2nd article you provide above. if you get stuck in some steps, you should read related chapters of the books that i recommended above.